# Prompt mobile browsers when trying to download zip files

Tags: android, ios, mobile, browser, file-io

I have a download link to a zip file. How can I send a prompt to the user if their device can't support downloading that file format?

Answer (score -1):

Link but befoe user download the zip file, you can set an unarchive tool in the backstage, if unarchive failed, it can prompt the user "Your device can't support downloading that file format"